# Does anyone have a nice formula for repeatedly differentiating a composite?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $$u\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},$$ $$f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n, \nabla=(\partial_{x_1},\ldots,\partial_{x_n})$$ is there a nice formula for
$$\nabla^k(f(u(x)))?$$
This seems to be something I have to work with a lot...

Comment: Is Faa di Bruno (multivariate version) not your friend? or look at this https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~nicholas/abstracts/FaadiBruno3.pdf

Comment: Ah thank you what an informative article with nice references :) I had actually never heard of Faa di Bruno's formula!!! XD if you want to leave your link in the answers I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: There's a lot of fun to be had with Faa di Bruno! But I'll say no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you can use the multivariate version of [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula): $$\frac{\partial^n (f\circ u)}{\partial x_1\ldots \partial x_n}=\sum_{\pi\in \Pi}( f^{(|\pi|)}\circ u) \prod_{B\in \pi}\frac{\partial^{|B|}u}{\prod_{j\in B}\partial x_j}, $$where $\pi$ runs through the set $\Pi$ of partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\} $ and $B$ denotes an element of the partition $\pi$. The absolute values denote cardinalities, of course.